# Does a SIM Card need to be inserted when getting GPS data using BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, I want to get GPS data using a BroadcastReceiver. If I test on a device  without a SIM card inserted, i can't get GPS data. So, my question is: Is a SIM Card needed to be inserted in the device to get GPS Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have access to any network to get a GPS location on Android. But need Internet Connection.

So first check below points.

- You have added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your manifest's permissions
- GPS satellites are enabled in the phone's settings.
- check that you are not indoors (signals from satellites 20,000 km
  above do not like roofs and walls)

Comment: I have added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your manifest's permissions, GPS satellites are enabled in the phone's settings, and mobile under without roof. i want to get GPS data in background service.